# PHP, DOM - remove first several nodes

Tags: php, xml, dom

The xml file looks like this:

```
<newVotes>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_524700002.jpg" id="1"/>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_5317gg.jpg" id="2"/>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_5393.jpg" id="3"/>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_2299.jpg" id="4"/>    
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_4977.jpg" id="5"/>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_4977BW.jpg" id="6"/>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_4914.jpg" id="7"/>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="flowergirl.jpg" id="8"/>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_5393.jpg" id="9"/>
    <image details="14.10.11" path="/test/content/pictures3/" image_name="PIC_2299.jpg" id="10"/>
</newVotes>
```

I don't know how many "image" nodes will contain my xml, and how many of them goes to remove (it's dynamic amount variable comes from flash module) My question is how to delete for example first 5 "image" nodes in xml, using PHP?

Especialy added "id" nodes because I thought I can delete them using Xpath somehow, but with no lucky...

Thanks for any help.
Artur.

Comment: What do you mean with "delete"? You want to create another file without the first X nodes or just display all the nodes but the first X.

Comment: If you were to use one of the simpler DOM [wrapper APIs](http://api.querypath.org/docs/class_query_path.html) then it's as simple as `qp($xml)->find("image")->slice(0,5)->remove();`. Also the problem with your IDs is that they are not allowed to be numeric.

Comment: **@AurelioDeRosa**, The thing I want to do is load XML, remove dynamic amount of "image" nodes(for example 5 first childNodes) and save changes in xml file.

Comment: **@mario**, it would be perfect, but I don't like have tons of files and long code. I hope it can be done without wrappers, but if there's no other option, then I'll have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Done... It was pretty simple:

```
$filesLimit = $_POST['_limit'];
$rateElement = $news_dom->getElementsByTagName('image');
$numberOfFiles = $rateElement->length;
$m = $numberOfFiles - $filesLimit + 1;
if($numberOfFiles>=$filesLimit){         
    for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
        $nodesToRemove = $rateElement->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($rateElement->item(0));   
    } 
}
```